# Tableau Desktop: Background images loading order

Tags: image, png, overlay, tableau-api

I'm trying to overlay png as background images. Do you know in which order Tableau load images ? (it does not seem to be by names)

I encounter an issue when I overlay more than 8 png. The order specified by name is not respected :/.

Thank you in advance for your help .

Alex

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But if your goal is simply to stack some images, then you can use a dashboard and stack floating image components in whatever order you want. That won't help if you are trying to display data above images.

Comment: I suspect you may get help on this if you provide more information and/or a screenshot to help provide the appropriate context. Also, specify if this is in regards to behavior on `Desktop` or `Server`.